# Magento site showing "not found" on clicking page link after migration the server

Tags: php, .htaccess, magento

I have migrate my site from one server to another server. Now it showing its landing page, But when i click on any link then it showing page **not found**. If i manually put `index.php` with my site then its working.

Example:

**mysite.com** this page is opening perfectly.

**mysite.com/about** this page showing error.

**mysite.com/index.php/about** this page is also working.

On my site every link is without `index.php`

what should i do?? in magento or .htaccess file

Answer (score 0):

Create .htaccess file in root folder, with following content

```
RewriteEngine on 

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)(?<!\.php)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
```